# Xamarin Forms Grid Row not shrinking

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms Page with an editor that is set to expand as text is added which works fine.

However, when I remove the text, the editor size decreases but the row containing the editor doesn't decrease in the same fashion.

Is there anyway to decrease the grid height in the same fashion as the editor?

I've created a repro at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJf8RkTPm5_3QWjoFpA1Ju6IcYY3vvSS/view?usp=sharing.

My Main XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Test.Controls"
             x:Class="Test.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" xmlns:controls1="clr-namespace:Test.Controls"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True">

    <!--<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="+"
                 Order="Primary"
                 Priority="0" 
                 Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>-->

    <controls1:KeyboardView x:Name="MainScroll" BackgroundColor="LightGray" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="1">
        
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
         
            <RowDefinition x:Name="PostGrid">
                <RowDefinition.Height>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GridLength">
                        <On Platform="Android">20</On>
                        <On Platform="iOS">Auto</On>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </RowDefinition.Height>
            </RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <ListView
        x:Name="lstMessages"
         BackgroundColor="White"
        HasUnevenRows="true"
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
       Grid.Row="0"
        
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        ItemsSource="{ Binding Messages }">


            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>


                

                        <StackLayout
        Spacing="0"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        Padding="10, 5, 10, 5"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

                            <Image
            Source="{ Binding Messageimg}"
            Style="{ StaticResource Avatar }"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            TranslationX="8"
            TranslationY="14" />

                            <StackLayout
            Padding="10, 0, 10, 0"
            Spacing="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                <StackLayout
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Spacing="0"
                Padding="10">
                                    <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label
                    Text="{ Binding Msgcattext }"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
FontAttributes="Bold"
                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }"
                                        FontFamily="GothamBold.otf"
                        />

                                        <Label
                        Style="{ StaticResource LabelBoldStyle }"
                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }"
                        
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                        FontFamily="GothamBold.otf"/>

                                        <!--<Label
                        Style=" {StaticResource FontIcon }"
                        Text="{ x:Static local:GrialIconsFont.Paperclip }"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        IsVisible="{ Binding HasAttachment }"
                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }" />-->

                                        <Label
                        Text="{ Binding CreatedAtString }"
                        FontSize="12"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        FontFamily="GothamBold.otf"/>

                                    </StackLayout>



                                    <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Padding="0,8,0,0">

                                        <Label
                        Text="{ Binding Msgtext}"
                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        MaxLines="2"
                                        FontFamily="GothamBold.otf"/>

                                        <Label
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                        FontSize="16"
                        WidthRequest="24"
                        Style="{ StaticResource FontIcon }"
FontFamily="GothamBold.otf"
                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource RatingsColor }" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

         <ActivityIndicator x:Name="postActivity" Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="False" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Color="Black"></ActivityIndicator>


        
        
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btmGrid" BackgroundColor="Gray">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                       <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Start">


                <Image x:Name="imgMsgCat" IsVisible="True" Source="xam.png" WidthRequest="30" Margin="5,5,0,0" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0">

                  
                </Image>


                 

            <controls1:DoneEditor IsVisible="True" x:Name="Editor"  Placeholder="Type a message..." AutoSize="TextChanges" WidthRequest="300" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="0,5,0,0"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="Medium">
               
            </controls1:DoneEditor>

                        
               

                <Image x:Name="imgSend" WidthRequest="30" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="30" Source="xam.png" Grid.Column="3" IsVisible="True" Margin="0,5,5,0" >
                   
                </Image>

                <ActivityIndicator x:Name="isSending" Grid.Column="3" IsVisible="False" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Color="Black"></ActivityIndicator>

                        
                         </StackLayout>
             
            </Grid>


    </controls1:KeyboardView>
</ContentPage>
```

The nested grid (with a Grid.Row of 1), expands in height as the editor expands in height, but doesn't decrease in the same way. The grid row stays at whatever the max height reached by the editor was.

Comment: Please, consider putting code samples inside a question

Comment: Added in the code sample

Comment: Are you referring to the gray background of the input box's background display incorrectly?

Comment: Yeah, I used the gray to highlight the issue. There are minimal margins before input box text entry, but if you add text to the box that it spans multiple lines and then remove all text, the margin is different than before you started.

Comment: I tested your code, the background color will be high when input, and normal low after delete.

Comment: I appear to be getting a different behaviour - I will produce a demo video later today.